# Matching flag image with country name:

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a drop down menu with country names that is submitted to a database.  I want to display an image of the country's flag on end-users profiles.  I have a folder in the root with all the flag icons.

How would I go about this?

I am able to grab the users country name but now I have this to use that name to grab the image out of the image folder.

```
 Flag_image.ImageUrl = "~/images/"countryTESTLabel.Text.ToString.Replace("_", " ")".png";
```

Comment: Associate each flag filename with a country in your DB

Comment: That's what I am thinking so just match the name with the image and database entry like when you validate?

Comment: say country code is UK, the filename for the flag icon can be flag_UK. Then for CA it's flag_CA...

Comment: I already have the drop down menu populated with the country names from a txt file.  I also have a folder in my images folder with all the flags.  So now it is just a matter of writing the code.   Which is what I am trying to figure out....what would be the best way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@ Jason, Upload/insert each of the flag images (image path to your folder) with their country name in your DB, and in your page bind the country name in dropdownlist. Note, this country name that will drop down will be unique because of their ID, which also holds the image path name of your folder. Hence when end user insert the country name from drop down, it will display the image of the flag which is associated with that particular Country name ID. You can use GridView to populate the user profile with image.
If anything more, ping me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Here is the code I used.

```
string checkCountryQuery = "select Country from userDataTable where Username = '" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
        MySqlCommand country_comm = new MySqlCommand(checkCountryQuery, cn);
        string country = country_comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace("_", " ");

        countryTESTLabel.Text = country;
        Flag_image.ImageUrl = @"../images/Flags/" + countryTESTLabel.Text.Replace(" ", "_") + ".png";
        countryTESTLabel.Visible = false;
```